# How to redirect to an extension page in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my web application i want to put a code that upon that execution it should redirect the current tab to some extension page?

If i do

window.location = 'chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj';

it redirects me to 'about://blank' not on that particular extension page.

[image]

Can some one help me out how to achieve the same.

Comment: any specific reason.? any link to that page that explain reason behind this.
any workaround for the same?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'd assume it's for security reasons.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Your comment is incorrect. Redirecting to an extension page *is* possible. The extension page has to exist though, *and* the extension has to co-operate by declaring the page in [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: @RobW: I have LastPass installed and I tried to do `window.location = 'chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/homelocal2.html';` and I see the same behavior.  It just brings me to a blank page.  Though you could still be right, I didn't check LastPass' manifest.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Navigating only works if the page is declared in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). If I look in LastPass's source code (using the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin)), I don't see "homelocal2.html", hence your redirect fails. But if you pick one of the pages that are listed, e.g. "overlay.html", then the redirect succeeds.

Comment: I have inserted web_accessible_resources information as guided in link. but it still does not work. I am also using manifest version 2

Comment: @Koka Did you reload the extension after editing manifest.json?

Comment: Yes, i have confirmed. i have inserted it this way "web_accessible_resources": [
        "option.html"
    ]. And Reloaded it.  it does not work. what i am missing.?

Comment: "It just brings me to a blank page" - please check JavaScript errors for this page.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to put all the resources of your chrome extension to the `web_accessible_resources`.

You also need to trigger redirect behavior. You can do it with `content_scripts` and you will need `permissions` for the specific domain.

Eventually you will have **mainfest.json** like:

```
    "permissions": [
        "*://example.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["injection.js"],
        "matches": ["*://www.example.com/*", "*://example.com/*"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "index.html",
        "main.js",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
```

And **injection.js** like:

```
location = 'chrome-extension://'+chrome.runtime.id+'/index.html';
```

Comment: I have: "web_accessible_resources": [{"resources": ["*"],"matches": ["<all_urls>"]}] and it still doesn't work. I have MV3 and receive an error: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-zeYLOGjDUEFNfFuC62JDSnYb6MFW4QnA1/5JWQZ9d8Y='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."